# Wordpress: Conditionally show stripped tag or post title. "Array" gets printed

Tags: arrays, wordpress, tags, conditional-statements, title

What I'm trying to achieve:
Show either the post tag (without the link) or the title.
If a tag exists, that gets printed if it doesn't, the title gets used.

Issue: I've used [get_the_tags()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) as suggested in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) to get the tag without the link and that works, yet it gets the word "Array" printed as a preffix, too.

```
<?php 
 if( has_tag() )
 { 
 echo $posttags = get_the_tags();
 if ($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
   }
 } 
 }
 else { echo the_title(); };
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would categorize your question under [Stack Exchange Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Post your question there and it will get much faster response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echo ing `$posttags` which is an array. If you **echo** an `array` it will echo **array** as output

```
<?php 
 if( has_tag() )
 { 
 This is printing Array as prefix ----> echo $posttags = get_the_tags();
 if ($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
   }
 } 
 }
 else { echo the_title(); };
?>
```

Please remove that echo , so your new code will be

```
<?php 
 if( has_tag() )
 { 
 $posttags = get_the_tags();
 if ($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
   }
 } 
 }
 else { echo the_title(); };
?>
```

Hope this helps you